# Save and open vbs script programmatically

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I have searched a lot on this method but no way

I want my VB Program as once opened it gives user some messages using vbs script file
so once program is opened the vbs file saved in temp and be ran to say the message to user

i have used this code with the vbs file imported to Resources
but unfortunately it works only with one line script not script with many lines

```
    Dim Variable As String = Environ("temp") & "Message.vbs"
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(Variable) Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Variable, My.Resources.Message)
    End If
    Process.Start(Variable)
```

i have used this second code as well but it gives error in compilation because of Save

```
    Dim Variable As String = Environ("temp") & "\Message.vbs"
    IO.File.Delete(Variable)
    My.Resources.Access.Save(Variable )
    Shell("explorer" & Variable )
```

Please Help me with this code, i have spend a long time to get solution but nothing

Thanks in advance

Comment: vb.net and vb6 are not the same thing. This appears to be .NET.

Comment: @jac, I think, he wants to save `vb-script`, which has vb6 syntax, to hard disk and launch it.

Comment: @T.S.: There is a specific tag for vbscript. .NET is already present (in vb.net), so there's no point in tagging it with that separately. The question asks about saving and launching a vbscript file from vb.net.

Comment: What do you mean by "it only works with one line script"? Are you saying that only one line is written to the file, or are you saying that multiple lines are written, but incorrectly?

Comment: @jac i mean with one line script like that simple one x=msgbox("Your Text Here" ,0, "Your Title Here") but for more complicated script, errors appear when script exexcuted i think the reason is that the code takes one dimension only –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some minor changes to your first example and created a simple vbs file. The first change is because a VB script file is a just a text file I added the resource as a text file and changed the WriteAllBytes statement to WriteAllText. Second, because `WriteAllText`, (and `WriteAllBytes` also), overwrite the file if it already exists I eliminated the If statement. You may still want that, in case you really do not want to overwrite the file. Finally, I added a backslash to the beginning of the filename to create the file in the temp folder. Otherwise you get *drive:\temppath\*tempMessage.vbs". This executed my simple script file just fine.

.NET code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Variable As String = Environ("temp") & "\Message.vbs"

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Variable, My.Resources.hello)
    Process.Start(Variable)
End Sub
```

My VBScript file:

```
MsgBox "Hello World", 0,"Messagebox #1"
MsgBox "My name is Fred", 0,"Messagebox #2"
MsgBox "I have to go now", 0,"Messagebox #3"
```